# Symfony 2 The referenced column name id has to be a primary key column

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

Having failed to find a suitable answer to this, I am posting here. Although, this message makes little sense since there is no referenced column called id here.

I'm referencing an existing OpenCart 1.5 database but with additional entities specific for the Symfony 2 CRM that's hooked up to it. The mappings are extremely tricky to master in this case but there's one which I cannot figure out.

> - The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language'.

Oc49Language is an existing OpenCart entity, but there is no column called `id`, only `language_id` - and there is no mention of `id` in the entity itself, nor any mappings.

Here's the `Oc49Language` entity:

```
/**
 * Oc49Language
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="oc49_language", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="name", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\Oc49LanguageRepository")
 */
class Oc49Language
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locale", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="directory", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $directory;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sort_order", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $sortOrder;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Species", inversedBy="languageName")
     */
    private $species;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $languageId;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->species = new ArrayCollection();
    }
.... etc.
```

I also see an ORMException message in console when trying to validate:

> Column name `id` referenced for relation from
>   AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language towards AppBundle\Entity\Species does
>   not exist.

Which is true - it doesn't exist; but there is also no reference to it either!

Am I missing something really obvious here or is it something a little more complex? This is the final mapping error out of all I was trying to fix but this one is really baffling me, so any help appreciated.

EDIT: as requested, this is the Species Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Species
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="species")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\SpeciesRepository")
 */
class Species
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="note", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $note;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language_id", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $languageId;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language", mappedBy="species")
     */
    private $languageName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Breed", mappedBy="species" )
     */
    private $breed;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Pet", inversedBy="species" )
     */
    private $pet;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Illness", mappedBy="species")
     */
    private $illness;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->breed = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->pet = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->illness = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every entity class must have a Primary key.

You can select the field that serves as the identifier with the @Id annotation.

Reference: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

---

**Edit:**
In the Species entity, replace:

```
     /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language", mappedBy="species")
     */
    private $languageName;
```

with:

```
     /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Oc49Language", mappedBy="species")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="languageId")
     */
    private $languageName;
```

Comment: That's not the problem - if you read the code I posted, you'll see the Primary key is called `language_id` - I'm trying to figure out where the  referenced column name it's claiming is a problem actually is.

Comment: Can you post the entity AppBundle\Entity\Species ? You may have specified the mapped column as Id, and not languageId

Comment: By default, the join column is "Id", you need to specify the new one if you choose to change it.

Comment: * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="languageId")

Comment: Where would I add that? I haven't changed it, that's just how OpenCart names them

Comment: in the Species entity, over the attribut "languageName"